Karak: Curse during Sprint of Hannah the Acrobat
The following scenario came up in a game of the Karak board game with the Regent expansion:
Hannah the acrobat has the "Sprint" ability which allows her to move 8 tiles through discovered terrain.
What happens if a curse chamber is on the path to the intended goal if Hannah rolls low and gets the curse during the movement?
I see two possible interpretations:

Hannah may finish the sprint full distance
Hannah has to stop after 4 tiles


This question was asked as well at BGG (with no answer yet).
From my reading of the rules the Acrobat should be able to use the full 8 tiles this turn. The rules say:

Sprint. Because the Acrobat is an excellent sprinter, at the beginning
of her turn, she can announce that she will sprint and then travel a
distance of up to 8 already-discovered tiles.

The curse is preventing you from using abilities on your card but in this case, the ability is already used, the curse will affect you the next turn and prevent you from sprinting again.

Thanks for that link! So while there is no official answer the consensus seems to be option 1: finish the sprint
